# Randomizer in Nunit 3

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

I'm migrating my projects from NUnit 2.6.3 to 3.2.1. I figured out that the "Randomizer" class moved from "NUnit.Framework" to "NUnit.Framework.Internal", but I can't find the method Randomizer.GetDoubles or any equivalent.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Randomizer class has been moved, and is now accessible through `TestContext.CurrentContext.Random`.

There is no longer a `Randomizer.GetDoubles`, but there is a `Randomizer.NextDouble(double min, double max)` method.

[[Docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Randomizer-Methods)]

Comment: So I need to rewrite the _GetDoubles_ method using _NextDouble_ ? why a such decision ?

Comment: @atrwsr they did a lot of breaking changes and I'm struggling to migrate my code to v3. It's like a big wall, I think many of the changes were mistakenly breaking.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used a `Randomizer` with a seed together with `GetDoubles` you can replace that code in NUnit 3:

```
var randomizer = new Randomizer(seed);
double[] values = Enumerable.Repeat(randomizer.NextDouble(min, max), times).ToArray();
```

The `Randomizer` class is available through the `NUnit.Framework.Internal` namespace.

Comment: Hi Dejan, I used your method but didn't get the expected result.the values all same.

Comment: @Leal.li: did you try with different seeds?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I mean, I set the same seeds by times get the random value, it only gets the same value. if by setting the different seeds, I want to test 1000 times, does that mean I need to set 1000 seeds?Is it too unfriendly?Can't it be as convenient as "[Random(-128, 127, 3)]"

Comment: @Leal.li: I think you're doing something wrong. Why don't you setup another SO question and show a small console app to show what you're doing so people can help you. Definitely, to get 1000 random numbers you don't need 1000 seed. However, the same seed will always generate the same sequence of random numbers - and it is important to do so, so you get repeatable results.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry.I tried to generate a set of test Numbers by means of Randomizer class methods，and by the Nunit ValueSource attribute import these test numbers.he following is my current approach.

Comment: For better typesetting, I added a new answer.Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

@Dejan
   Yes, I am sorry.I tried to generate a set of test Numbers by means of `Randomizer` class methods，and by the Nunit `ValueSource` attribute import these test numbers.The following is my current approach.
   I know this method is not good, so I would like to know other good methods.

```
    public static double[] GetDoubleInRangeNums()
    {
        List<double> list = new List<double>();
        double k = 0;
        list.Add(double.MinValue);
        list.Add(double.MaxValue);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            k = randomizer.NextDouble(double.MaxValue);
            if (!list.Contains(k))
            {
                list.Add(k);
            }
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }

    [Test]
    [Category("DataType.Double")]
    public void DoubleInRangeTest([ValueSource("GetDoubleInRangeNums")]double value, [Values(1)]int flag)
    {
        string tableName = "DataTypeDouble";
        string columnType = "double precision";
        CreateTable(tableName, columnType);
        EsgynDbDataType_FloatPointNum(tableName, value, value, EsgynDBType.Double, flag);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. :)